# Multi-select cell in UITableView in sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with numerous cells. I'm able to multi select cells but what I want is that user only can select multiple cells in sequence. ie if user has selected 2nd row then he/she only can select 3rd cell then 4th in sequence, doesn't allow to select random cells.

Here is what I've done:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return arrPackages.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PurchaseListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PurchaseListTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *dict = [arrPackages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblPackageName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"package_name"];
    cell.lblDiscount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You save: %@%%",[dict valueForKey:@"discount"]];
    cell.lblLastAmount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"package_price"]];

    NSString *strPaymentStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"payment_status"]];
    if ([strPaymentStatus isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else{
        cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    /*
     NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your String here"];
     [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
     value:@2
     range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
     */
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //  NSDictionary *dict = [_arrModuleData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete | UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @AshleyMills Thank you for your response. Here I've Updated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the tableview delegate method [`tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614943-tableview) and return `nil` if you don't want to select the current index path, else you just return the given index path.

*Objective-C:*

```
-(NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    if (selectedIndexPaths == nil || selectedIndexPaths.count == 0) {
        return indexPath;
    }

    NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *sortedIndexPaths = [[selectedIndexPaths sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSIndexPath  * _Nonnull index1, NSIndexPath * _Nonnull index2) {
        return index1.row < index2.row;
    }] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"section = %d", indexPath.section]];

    if (indexPath.row >= sortedIndexPaths[0].row &&
        indexPath.row <= sortedIndexPaths[sortedIndexPaths.count-1].row) {
        return indexPath;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

*Swift:*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    guard let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows,
        selectedIndexPaths.count > 0 else {
            return indexPath
    }

    let indexes = selectedIndexPaths
        .filter { $0.section == indexPath.section }
        .sorted()

    if let first = indexes.first,
        let last = indexes.last,
        indexPath.row >= first.row - 1 && indexPath.row <= last.row + 1 {
        return indexPath
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

Of course you should code a similar behavior for `tableView(_:willDeselectRowAt:)`

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should be in the appropriate language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've asked for objective-c

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention to the tags. Here is the updated answer with Obj-C.